# how to parse url with mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, function, stored-procedures, parse-url

`Mssql` have a function `parseURL`.
But we have moved our database from `mssql` to `mysql`.

Mysql doesnot have `parse url`, Now we need to create `parseURL` function manually.

How to create `parse url` function in `mysql`?

this is mssql function

`

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON  
SET ANSI_NULLS ON  
GO  
CREATE      FUNCTION [dbo].[parseURL]  (@strURL varchar(1000))  
RETURNS varchar(1000)  
AS  
BEGIN  
IF CHARINDEX('http://',@strURL) > 0 OR CHARINDEX('https://',@strURL) > 0  
-- Ghetto-tastic  
SELECT @strURL = REPLACE(@strURL,'https://','')  
SELECT @strURL = REPLACE(@strURL,'http://','')  
SELECT @strURL = REPLACE(@strURL,'www','')  
-- Remove everything after "/" if one exists  
IF CHARINDEX('/',@strURL) > 0 (SELECT @strURL = LEFT(@strURL,CHARINDEX('/',@strURL)-1))  

-- Optional: Remove subdomains but differentiate between www.google.com and www.google.com.au  
IF (LEN(@strURL)LEN(REPLACE(@strURL,'.','')))/LEN('.') < 3 - if there are less than 3 periods  
SELECT @strURL = PARSENAME(@strURL,2) + '.' + PARSENAME(@strURL,1)  
ELSE -- It's likely a google.co.uk, or google.com.au  
SELECT @strURL = PARSENAME(@strURL,3) + '.' + PARSENAME(@strURL,2) + '.' + PARSENAME(@strURL,1)  
RETURN @strURL  
END  
GO
```

`

Comment: Does mssql really hve a `parseUrl()` function?

Comment: yep, mssql have parseurl() function.

Comment: Show us the documentation on MSDN?

Comment: @vchakoshy can you show proof of this? There is a `ParseURL()` method in `Shlwapi.dll` but as far as I know this is not directly accessible to SQL Server.

Comment: @AaronBertrand im so sorry this function not in mssql functions. i added this to question

Comment: @Widor you're right. this is my mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server doesn't have a function called `parseURL` either. Wherever you're calling this function, run:

```
EXEC sp_helptext 'parseURL';
```

If you show us the definition of the function, we can help you translate it and create an equivalent function for MySQL.